# Is there any way to disable ajax call on sorting in Jquery Datatables? I need client side sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10, jquery-datatables-editor

Currently there is no ajax source in my code. I am using simple initialization of Jquery Datatables. Below is the code

```
  $('#MyRequestList').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "aLengthMenu": [
        [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
        [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
        ],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
```

I want default sorting which should be client side sorting.
Please help.

Comment: if there is no `ajax` call to fetch data then sorting will be client side itself! What's your doubt then? Did you try that?

Comment: ...is it currently using ajax for sorting?

Comment: Yes When I click on column header to sort its call  my mvc action. Then its again send undefined parameter.

Comment: did you try anything? where did you stuck. If you're able to sort it on server side, what's the problem you are facing to sort in on client side through jQuery

Comment: didn't got anything to try... :(

Comment: I don't want to sort it server side. I have small data which can be sort client efficiently. But everytime I click on the header every time page loads and return back.

Comment: Its hits the action method of same page. http://localhost:49974/request/myrequest/undefined
with undefined as parameter

Comment: Most likely you have a click event handler attached elsewhere that causes the request, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com thanx man I was looking for the click event and I found one, a silly mistake from my end. Thanks Man

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#MyRequestList').DataTable( {
    "order": [[ COLUMN_NUMBER, "desc"/"asc" ]]
} );
});
```

Comment: still its reloading the page. I just want to remove that load.

Comment: do not use intput type submit, use input type button and call above function on button click.